# How to right align something in Powershell prompt?

Tags: git, powershell

I'm trying to right align the `Write-VcsStatus` part of posh-git in my prompt. Essentially, my prompt lists out my hostname and current directory on the left and currently prints git status info right after the current directory. I want this git status to be right justified, but I can't figure out how to do this.

This is my prompt code:

```
Import-Module posh-git
function prompt {
     Update-NavigationHistory $pwd.Path
     Write-Host ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName() + ": ") -nonewline -foregroundcolor DarkCyan
     Write-Host (([string]$pwd).Replace("C:\Users\user", "~")) -nonewline -foregroundcolor DarkYellow
     Write-VcsStatus
     Write-Host
     Write-Host ($([char]0x2192)) -nonewline
     return " "
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of right aligned text, using `$Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition`.

**NOTE:** This does not work in Powershell_ISE, because it uses a non-standard console host.

```ps
function Global:prompt {
     $oc = $host.ui.RawUI.ForegroundColor
     $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "DarkCyan"
     $Host.UI.Write([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName() + ": ")
     $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "Yellow"
     $Host.UI.Write(([string]$pwd).Replace("C:\Users\user", "~")) 
     $message = "This text is right aligned"
     $startposx = $Host.UI.RawUI.windowsize.width - $message.length
     $startposy = $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition.Y
     $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates $startposx,$startposy
     $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "DarkGreen"
     $Host.UI.Write($message)
     $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $oc
     $Host.UI.Write($([char]0x2192))
     return " "
 }
```

Comment: Why did you add the "Global" tag before prompt? And also, where can I get documentation on things like $Host? I can't find it anywhere. I'm trying to learn powershell, but it's really hard finding resources on global variables and parameters.

Comment: The "Global" tag is needed to make it work on 2012 (My OS) if you run as Administrator. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any real documentation for the PS $host. Although there are a few examples on this site if you do a search.

Comment: How do you capture the output of a cmdlet? For example, I have this function Write-VcsStatus. I want to capture the output of that and put it into $message. How can I do that?

Comment: @asuna Read this: [`Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847768.aspx).

Comment: Depends on what the function does. If it returns a string it may be as easy as $ message = Write-VcsStaus, but if it writes to console it will be hard.